# How to change the default password for admin account in a Compose for MongoDB service?

Tags: ibm-cloud

In IBM Cloud, when creating a Compose for MongoDB service, an 'admin' account is created in the new mongoDB.  This is the account displayed in the Connection Strings panel in the overview page of the service.  A default password is assigned.

How can I change the password of this account without breaking the IBM Cloud features on top of this mongoDB server ?

I tried changing the password at mongoDB level directly (with the db.changeUserPassword command).  But after that, all backups triggered by IBM Cloud platform were broken, until I restored the original password.